# Multiple Dependency Inection Tsyringe

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection

I'm trying to implement a cascading with tsyringe.

I have a singleton database class that has to be injected in a service class that have to be injected in a controller class:

```js
@injectable()
class DashboardDAO implements IDashboardDAO {...}

@injectable()
class DashboardService implements IDashboardService {
    construtor(@inject('DashboardDAO') private dashboardDao: IDashboardDAO){}
}

@injectable()
class DashboardController {
    construtor(@inject('DashboardService') private dashboardService: IDashboardService){}
}
```

in my container i have the following configuration.

```js
/** REPOSITORIES */
container.registerSingleton<IDashboardDAO>('DashboardDAO', DashboardDAO);

/** SERVICES */
container.registerSingleton<IDashboardService>('DashboardService', DashboardService);
```

I whould like to instantiate the controller with everything injected, something like this:

```js
const controller = container.resolve(DashboardController);
```

It couldn't resolve... I'm getting the following error:

> Attempted to resolve unregistered dependency token

If I do the code below works fine, but i would like to resolve the controller with all injections.

```js
container.resolve(DashboardService);
```

Anyone knows why?

Tks!

Comment: Does `container.resolve('DashboardService')` work?

Comment: works and I don't have to register the service, and the paramenter DashboardService must be the class name not a string

Comment: @ReculosGerbiNeto are you able to resolve this ?

Comment: @kbvishnu not really, we did a workaround, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The services implementing interfaces are registered correctly, though a minor improvement would be to omit the template type when registering, as it doesn't add anything:

```
container.registerSingleton('DashboardDAO', DashboardDAO);
container.registerSingleton('DashboardService', DashboardService);
```

I'd recommend using a symbol instead of a hard-coded string, but that's a minor point.

The issue is that you marked the `DashboardController` class as injectable but didn't tell `tsyringe` how to resolve the class. One way is to mark it as a singleton:

```
@singleton()
class DashboardController {...}
```

or:

```
container.registerSingleton(DashboardController)
```

Then resolving with `container.resolve(DashboardController)` should work fine.

Comment: I have done almost similar to the above.  I have a separate files interface, implementation, controllers and route. I am resolving the dependencies/registering it in another file with one function and export it. `This is to consolidate all DI into one place and try to invoke the call from app's constructor.`  However i am getting the same error above. But if I make a call to the function in the  file in route then it was able to resolve. Suppose my route is `/seller` and I have a `/sellerloc` also in a separate file, shall I need to invoke the same for resolving the deps ?

Comment: I suggest post a new question, and include enough code to explain the situation, or a link to a fiddle. I also like to put all the initial setup in a single file, and it works well, so I may be able to assist.

Comment: This got resolved thnks